# Jquery cookies not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie and then use the result to style the page. This works on Chrome but not firefox or IE:

Set the cookie page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/site/javascript/jquery.cookie.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$.cookie('newCookie', 'set11');
</script>
```

Use the cookie page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/site/javascript/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function setHomePage() {
if ($.cookie('newCookie') === 'set11')
{
$('#asas').css('width', '500px');
}
}
</script>
```

then....

```
<body class="threeCol" onload="setHomePage()"

 <div id="asas"></div>
```

The cookie is being set and this is confirmed in Firefox and Chrome. The new style is added in Chrome but not Firefox

There are no js errors in the console but when I try to run the function manually in Firefox it states it is undefined.

```
ReferenceError: setHomepage is not defined
```

Any ideas?

**Update**
Added an alert to see if there was any failing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert ("page111");
function setHomePage() {
if ($.cookie('newCookie') === "set11")
{
$('#asas').css('width', '500px');
alert ("page");
}
alert ("page1");
}
</script>
```

alert ("page"); fails indicating an issue with the if statement. If I look at the cookies within Firefox it is set correctly. Is there in issues/differences in format?

alert ("page"); works in Chrome.

If I echo out the cookie value:
var test = $.cookie('newCookie');
alert (test);

Chrome show the correct value, IE and Firefox displays undefined.

Comment: Are you incognito mode or Private browsing mode?

Comment: @Ali No, normal browsing mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as per your requirements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function setHomePage() {
            if ($.cookie('newCookie') === 'set11')
            {
                $('#asas').css({'border': '1px solid red', 'width':'200px' , 'height' : '200px'});
            }
        }

        $.cookie('newCookie', 'set11');
    </script>

</head>
<body class="threeCol" onload="setHomePage()">
<div id="asas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple basic Javascript Cookie funciton

```
//get and set cookie functions
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
    x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
    x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if (x==c_name)
    {
        return unescape(y);
    }
    }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Hope this will help.